# Basic SSH port change not working on EC2 instance

Tags: ssh

I am trying to change the port of SSH on an EC2 instance, but I am not getting this to work.

What I am doing is the following:

Open the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Uncomment and change the line `Port 2345`

Save and close

run the command `service sshd restart`

Now I can still connect to port 22. And when I run the command `ssh -p 2345 localhost` i get:

> ssh: connect to host localhost port 2345: Connection refused

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be a typo, but if you want to change the port that sshd listens on, you need to edit the `Port` setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, not `ssh_config`.

Also, you're using two different port numbers above (2345 and 2232), but I'm sure that's a typo.

If it's not that, could you edit into your question the output of `iptables -L -n -v` so we can see your firewall rules?

Comment: Oh i see there are 2 files!!

Comment: Yes, because there are two pieces of software.  `ssh_config` controls the behaviour of ssh, that is, your local ssh client.  `sshd_config` controls the behaviour of sshd, that is, your local ssh server.

Comment: Yeah I was working in the wrong file. Such an idiot. Everything is ok now.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh_config` is the SSH client configuration file.

`sshd_config` is the SSH daemon (server) configuration file.

So, if you want to change the port for the ssh **server** You have to edit the `sshd_config` file,

Uncomment the line

> Port 22

and change port 22 to 2345.

After editing the file, restart the ssh service.

> /etc/init.d/sshd restart

And also allow ssh port in the iptables. and restart the iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something simple but you have Port 2345 in your config and then try to connect to 2232.

2345 != 2232

Comment: Oh no that was a mistake, Ill edit that.